# R Remove an integer element from a factor-type vector

Tags: r, typeof

I have the vector `foo`:

```
> foo

 983      984      985      986      987      988      989      990
cluster4 cluster4 cluster4 cluster1 cluster1 cluster1 cluster5 cluster5

Levels: cluster1  cluster4 cluster5  


typeof(foo)

    "integer"

class(foo)

    "factor"
```

How could I remove the element "983"? So I get:

```
> foo_removed

 984      985      986      987      988      989      990
cluster4 cluster4 cluster1 cluster1 cluster1 cluster5 cluster5

Levels: cluster1  cluster4 cluster5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `!is.na(as.numeric())` to identify the strings that are numeric and remove them.

```
onlynumbers <- "123.4"
onlyletters <- "abcd."
strings <- c(onlynumbers, onlyletters)
!is.na(as.numeric(strings))
[1]  TRUE FALSE
```

As you can see this is working, now the removal

```
result <- strings[is.na(as.numeric(strings))]
> result
[1] "abcd."
```

---

**EDIT** You should first convert your factors to character using `as.character.factor` and after you can reconvert using `as.factor`

---

**EDIT 2** to keep the names you could use `names(result) <- names(strings)[is.na(as.numeric(strings))]`

Comment: It works for the point, but it would be nice to retain the original "names" attributes (i.e. 984 985 986 987 988 989 990)

Answer (score 0):

To complement gpier's answer.

```
foo <- as.character.factor(foo)
foo_removed <-foo[-c(1)]
foo_removed <- as.factor(foo_removed)

> foo_removed

cluster4 cluster4 cluster1 cluster1 cluster1 cluster5 cluster5

Levels: cluster1  cluster4 cluster5
```